# How to reformat date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I am pulling the dates of various posts from a database. The dates are in the following format:

```
2009-08-12

Numeric Year - Numeric Month - Numeric Day
```

How can I reformat these dates to something more user friendly like:

```
August 12, 2009

Numeric Month Numeric Date, Numeric Year
```

Assuming that the date gotten from the mysql database is stored in a variable called:

```
$date = $row['date_selected'];
```

Comment: Is it stored as a string in this form, or is the date's MySQL field of type date? If so, you can format it right when doing the SELECT call.

Comment: It's when you instantly get 3 answers, all with the same two function calls, that you ought to realise the documentation would have given you the answer. For your reference: http://www.php.net/manual

Comment: @icio, I'll agree that this is a relatively easy question to look up, if you know where to look, but there are actually two methods under discussion below. Plus, I thought there were no questions too basic, as long as they're programming related. At least that's what Joel always seems to say on the podcast....

Comment: @sprugman Doesn't really matter. This entire subject has been asked on so many questions it is ridiculous.

Comment: @chacha102, if it's a duplicate question, then I suppose it should probably be closed as such. (I don't have those permissions.)

Comment: @sprugman I agree absolutely but I believe one of the most important lessons is how to use references and documentation. I have always found this a good thing to *really hammer home*. In this instance call it tough love, if you will. Anyway, let's end this somewhat arbitrary discussion -- it's not as if this kind of thing is going to stop!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`date("F d, Y", strtotime($input))`

Comment: You can't enforce correct handling by just calling strtotime. For example, somebody could switch the month and day around and strtotime would not handle it.

Comment: since this was selected as the answer, despite having fewer votes than @Billy's, I'll repeat my comment from @chacha's answer below:

The strtotime method is the 'standard', and if your server's locale settings expect month-day-year, it will work just fine, but @Billy's method is safer, assuming you have php 5.3 available, which on a shared host is definitely not a safe assumption yet.

Comment: Moreover UNIX epoch is about EOL in nearest future and looking to the future it is not recommended to use `strtotime()` if you have possibility to use `DateTime` object. + `strtotime()` is not always adequate and it has known issues, but answer will definitely work for the most cases.

Answer (score 69):

Unlike the `strtotime` based examples, this allows you to ensure the month and day are interpreted in the correct order regardless of locale settings specified on the server.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2009-08-12');
$output = $date->format('F j, Y');
```

Comment: +1: `DateTime` should always be preferred instead of `strtotime`.

Comment: You can actually do this on one line: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2009-08-12')->format('F j, Y');`

Comment: +1 This is the best answer. strtotime() isn't always correct as dd/mm/yyyy formats look exactly the same as mm/dd/yyyy formats.

Answer (score 6):

```
$new_format = date("Your Date String", strtotime($date));
```

See:
- http://php.net/strtotime
- http://php.net/date

Basically, if `strtotime()` can read it correctly, you can reformat it anyway you please.

In this case, `Year - Month - Day` is a properly recognized `strtotime()` format, this might not be the case for other formats.

Comment: You can't enforce correct handling by just calling strtotime. For example, somebody could switch the month and day around and strtotime would not handle it.

Comment: Like I said, if `strtotime()` can read it correctly, you can do it.

Comment: but there no to decise programmatically if a date is correctly formatted if you only have the string "2009-08-02". For that to be possible you would have to have seperate input fields for year, month and day.

Comment: @Femaref: Yes, but if you use DateTime::createFromFormat, at least it does range checking to ensure that if you meant for a month to be in that spot, it won't accept a value like 31

Comment: @Femaref: For example, is 2009-08-12 August 12, 2009, or is it December 8, 2009? There's no way to specify which one you want to strtotime.

Comment: @Billy But he isn't talking about a weird format. For this specific problem, there is no need for DateTime, as Year - Month - Day is a correct strtotime format.

Comment: @Chacha102: Sure, that'll work great until somebody tries to run the script on a server with different locale settings.

Comment: The strtotime method is the 'standard', and if your server's locale settings expect month-day-year, it will work just fine, but @Billy ONeal's method is safer, assuming you have php 5.3 available, which on a shared host is definitely not automatic yet.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider doing your date formatting in MySQL with your select statement:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %e, %Y') as date_selected
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the php function `strtotime`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

It'll parse a large number of date representations to a Unix timestamp.

Then use the `date` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
// February 1, 2005
print date ("F j, Y", mktime (0,0,0,14,1,2004));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using strtodate or explode to split the date into its different components, you can then use the date function with the appropriate format string:http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$date = "2009-08-12";
list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$date);
$formattedDate = date("F d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
```

Outputs: "August 12, 2009"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Date Formatter
/*
date: date you want to convert
format: its current format ie m-d-Y, m/d/Y, Y-m-d, Y/m/d
delimS: Current delimiter ie - or / or .
delimF: The delimiter you want for the result

NOTE: this will only convert m-d-Y to Y-m-d and back
*/
function dtform($date,$format,$delimS,$delimF){
    $dateFinal = '';
    if($format == 'm'.$delimS.'d'.$delimS.'Y'){
        $dateFinal_exp = explode($delimS,$date);
        $dateFinal = $dateFinal_exp[2].$delimF.$dateFinal_exp[0].$delimF.$dateFinal_exp[1];
    }else if($format == 'Y'.$delimS.'m'.$delimS.'d'){

        $dateFinal_exp = explode($delimS,$date);
        $dateFinal = $dateFinal_exp[1].$delimF.$dateFinal_exp[2].$delimF.$dateFinal_exp[0];
    }
    return $dateFinal;
}
?>
```