# PHP Convert datetime format

Tags: php, date, datetime

Is there a way in PHP to convert the date time format from the one in the left to the one on the right?

**1900-01-01T00:00:00-06:00** to **1900-01-01 00:00:00.000**

**2015-06-18T00:00:00-05:00** to **2015-06-18 00:00:00.000**

As you see I don't want to keep the timezone and want to get rid of the T and I believe the one in the right also has milliseconds.

Comment: A generic version to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754765/how-to-reformat-date-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since only the year month and day are pertinent, you can just use `date_format` to get that from your existing string, then concatenate your time to it, resulting in the string you're after.

```
date_format(new DateTime("1900-01-01T00:00:00-06:00"),"Y-m-d")." 00:00:00.000";
// 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!