# How to change the Date format in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i use this cod to show the invoice date

```
    $this->SetX(135);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $this->Cell(70,8,___('Date:')." ".$invoice['date'],0,0,'C',false);
```

but it show it in the format Y,m,d
and i want to show it in Format d,m,Y

how can i fix this please ?

Comment: Please specify exact version of your CakePHP - you used tags for both 2.x and 3.x, so its uncertain what version you are using. Please also show us what is hiding in your `$invoice['date']` - an output from `var_dump($invoice['date'])` should be sufficient.

Comment: also when add       `<?php    php > var_dump($invoice['date']);  ?>`  it print   `null`  and when use `<?php    php > var_dump($invoice);  ?> ` it show this result https://i.imgur.com/7wz8wBe.png   and for version i see in public_html/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt  that the version is `2.4.7`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reformat date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754765/how-to-reformat-date-in-php)

Comment: also i don't see how can i add a dateformat on this line  `$this->Cell(70,8,___('Date:')." ".$invoice['date'],0,0,'C',false);`  so that i can reformat the date format to m,d,y  , how can i fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using this cod :

```
        $this->Cell(70,8,___('Date:')." ".date("d-m-Y", strtotime($invoice['date'])),0,0,'C',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach is to use [CakeTime::format()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-CakeTime.html#_format):

`$this->Cell(70,8,___('Date:')." ".CakeTime::format($invoice['date'], '%d-%m-%Y'),0,0,'C',false);`