# Is there a way to convert between date formats and regexes with PHP?

Tags: php, date-format

I'm presuming I will have to build this myself, but before I re-invent the wheel ...

I have an input where someone can decide what date format to use. They can enter freetext and it will be interpreted as a [php date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Say someone enters `Y-m-d` as the date, is there a convertor to know that this is `YYYY-MM-DD` if I'm using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), `%Y-%m-%d` for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), and the (simplified version of the) regular expression would be `^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$` for mandatory and `^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)?$` for optional (I'd use a more better regex for real, this one is easier to see).

Should be pretty straightforward to create a class, I just want to check whether there is a way to do it already in PHP, and if not, whether there are any gotchas to watch out for.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to convert the date formats, not the dates themselves. For example a call to `conversion_function('Y-m-d', 'MySQL')` would return `%Y-%m-%d`, and a call to `conversion_function('Y-m-d', 'MomentJS')` would return `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: If your formats are one of the [many that are recognized by PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) you shouldn't need to worry about the format. All of the date formats you provided are recognized by PHP.

Comment: That doesn't really help me spit out the date format I need when I need `Y-m-d` for a `DATE_FORMAT()` in MySQL, or as a regular expression  in a javascript `match` command to check it was entered correctly on the client side.

Comment: Sure it does. That means you can use a very basic one liner to get the date in the format you want: `$YYYYMMDD = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourdate));`. PHP dates 101.

Comment: What I want is more like `$MySQLDateFormat = convert('Y-m-d', 'MySQL');`. `$MySQLDateFormat` would contain `%Y-%m-%d` after the function call.

Comment: This doesn't exist. You would need to write this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
```

I recently had to use the above for an API "type" validator. Works well

Comment: Kinda overkill considering the formats they listed can easily be handled by PHP datetime functions.

Comment: Well I believe he's going to end up down the path of validation, and that's a perfect way to validate date formats.

Comment: This validates if a date is good, regardless of the format, but it doesn't help me convert from one date format to another, or to a regex, from what I understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754765/how-to-reformat-date-in-php  and  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php  (unix timestamp)  .  But you bring up a good idea for a class that can detect(validate) date format then reformat it based on regex alone, which would be pretty neat